# Kotlin split string with multiple delimiter whitespace and comma

Tags: java, android, kotlin, split

so i have string like this = `"1, 2,3 , 4,  5  6 7 ,  8   ,9  10"`

this is the input of readline.string(), what kind of split delimiter do I need in order to create an array like this =`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

i tried to use  `.split("\\s".toRegex())` but it doesnt want to accept another string delimiter like `","`

Answer (score 1):

You have one or more of spaces and/or commas between items, so you can use

```
"[\\s,]+".toRegex()
```